# Syntastic won't load checkers on startup

Tags: gcc, vim, syntastic

I'm trying to setup Syntastic for C/C++ syntax checking with GCC. GCC is installed and available in the PATH. Here is the syntastic configuration from my .vimrc:

```
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

let g:syntastic_c_checkers = ['gcc']
let g:syntastic_cpp_checkers = ['gcc']
```

Nothing too spicy, the recommended base configuration and two variables defining gcc as the default checker for C and C++ files. But when I open a C/C++ file in vim, nothing happens. `:SyntasticInfo` yields no currently enabled checker. However, if I manually type in vim `:let g:syntastic_c_checkers = ['gcc']`, it begins to work. What's happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you verified that your `.vimrc` is loading?

Comment: There are plugins (f.i. Eclim) that just disable syntastic without asking.  Other plugins (f.i. YCM) need special configuration to let syntastic do its thing. Debugging all this is not suitable for [so]. Feel free to post to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues) instead.